# Joining different list data types into string

Tags: python, string, list, join

I need to join the elements of a list into a string (looks simple so far).

However this list has some elements that are strings and others that are numbers.

What I want to achieve is a string where the original strings are still quoted but the numbers are not:

Example:

```
mystring = ['text field', 24, 'text2', 55.45]
```

Expected output (this is actually a string, I removed the opening and closing quotes for clarity, the simple quotes must be part of the string!):

```
'text field', 24, 'text2', 55.45
```

What I tried so far:

```
>>> ', '.join(mystring)
```

then the interpreter complains about the int:

```
TypeError: sequence item 1: expected string, int found
```

If I try to map everything to string, then I miss the quotes for string.

```
>>> ', '.join(map(str,a))

'text field, 24, text2, 55.45'
```

Of course I could modify my original list to look like:

```
mylist2 = ["'text field'", 24, "'text2'", 55.45]
```

and then it works but I really want to keep my original list and achieve the desired result.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `repr`:

```
>>> mystring = ['text field', 24, 'text2', 55.45]
>>> ', '.join(map(repr, mystring))
"'text field', 24, 'text2', 55.45"
```

Comment: I like the use of `map`, however I'm wondering if there is any difference between using `map` or using list comprehension (@Willem solution)? I will post another question to ask if there is actually a difference or it's just a semantic preference.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki Don't post another question, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/python-list-comprehension-vs-map

Answer (score 3):

Simply convert the elements in the `.join` to a string by using the [`str(..)`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#func-str) builtin:

```
', '.join(str(x) for x in mystring)
```

If you want however to add quotation marks around your strings, you should use [`repr(..)`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#repr):

```
', '.join(repr(x) for x in mystring)
```

Example in the interactive shell:

```
$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> str('aa')
'aa'
>>> mystring = ['text field', 24, 'text2', 55.45]
>>> ', '.join(str(x) for x in mystring)
'text field, 24, text2, 55.45'
>>> ', '.join(repr(x) for x in mystring)
"'text field', 24, 'text2', 55.45"
```

Note that the double quotes (`"`) are not part of the actually string, they are there to show we are talking about a string.

Comment: Second option (with repr) works! Thanks. And yes, the double quotes are not part of the string (this is why in the question I removed them, just to avoid confusion)

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just take the string representation of the list and cut off the brackets? Sounds like that's what you're actually trying to achieve anyway.

```
>>> str(mystring)[1:-1]
"'text field', 24, 'text2', 55.45"
```

Answer (score 0):

An approach would be:

```
', '.join("'{}'".format(s) if isinstance(s, str) else str(s) for s in mystring)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> mystring = ['text field', 24, 'text2', 55.45]
>>> 
>>> ', '.join("'{}'".format(s) if isinstance(s, str) else str(s) for s in mystring)
"'text field', 24, 'text2', 55.45"
```